# Search Custom getFilter in custom List<Object>

Tags: android

I am having trouble implementing custom getFilter in custom arrayAdapter. Tried various codes but still no luck. Here is my custom array adapter.

```
public class CallSMSAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private final static int TYPE_CALL=1,TYPE_SMS=2;
    private List<Object> callSMSFeed = new ArrayList();
    private List<Object> contactListFiltered;
    // Context is not used here but may be required to
    // perform complex operations or call methods from outside
    private Context context;

    // Constructor
    public CallSMSAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    public void setCallSMSFeed(List<Object> callSMSFeed){
        this.callSMSFeed = callSMSFeed;
    }

    // We need to override this as we need to differentiate
    // which type viewHolder to be attached
    // This is being called from onBindViewHolder() method
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (callSMSFeed.get(position) instanceof SMS) {
            return TYPE_SMS;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // Invoked by layout manager to replace the contents of the views
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        int viewType=holder.getItemViewType();

                SMS sms=(SMS)callSMSFeed.get(position);
                ((SMSViewHolder)holder).showSmsDetails(sms);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){return callSMSFeed.size();}

    // Invoked by layout manager to create new views
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Attach layout for single cell
        int layout = 0;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // Identify viewType returned by getItemViewType(...)
        // and return ViewHolder Accordingly

                layout=R.layout.single_list_item2;
                View smsView = LayoutInflater
                        .from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder=new SMSViewHolder(smsView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    private void setFadeAnimation(View view) {
        AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(500);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

            }
        };
    }

    // Second ViewHolder of object type SMS
    // Reference to the views for each call items to display desired information
    public class SMSViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView senderNameTextView,smsContentTextView, smsTimeTextView;

        public SMSViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // Initiate view
            senderNameTextView =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pNametxt);
            smsContentTextView =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pName2txt);
            smsTimeTextView =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pJobProfiletxt);
        }

        public void showSmsDetails(SMS sms){
            // Attach values for each item
            String senderName   =sms.getSenderName();
            String smsContent   =sms.getSmsContent();
            String smsTime     =sms.getSmsTime();
            senderNameTextView.setText(senderName);
            smsContentTextView.setText(smsContent);
            smsTimeTextView.setText(smsTime);
        }
    }
}
```

SMS Class:

```
public class SMS {
   private String senderName,smsContent,smsTime;
       public SMS(String senderName, String smsContent, String smsTime) {
       this.senderName = senderName;
       this.smsContent = smsContent;
       this.smsTime = smsTime;
   }
   public String getSenderName() {
       return senderName;
   }
   public String getSmsContent() {
       return smsContent;
   }
   public String getSmsTime() {
       return smsTime;
   }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private RecyclerView recyclerView;
   private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
   private List<Object> callSMSList;
   private CallSMSAdapter callSMSAdapter;
       SearchView searchView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);
       recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
       // Set Layout Manager
       linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
       // Limiting the size
       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       // Initialize list items
       init();
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // listening to search query text change
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when query submitted
                callSMSAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when text is changed
                callSMSAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

   private void init(){
       callSMSList =new ArrayList<>();
       // Initiating Adapter
       callSMSAdapter =new CallSMSAdapter(RecyclerViewActivity.this);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(callSMSAdapter);
       // Adding some demo data(Call &amp; SMS Objects).
       // You can get them from your data server
       callSMSList.add(new SMS("Sandy","Hey, what's up?","9:42 AM"));
       callSMSList.add(new SMS("John","Are you writing blog?","9:48 AM"));
       callSMSList.add(new SMS("Kora","Thanks dude","9:57 AM"));
       callSMSList.add(new SMS("Nick","Let's hang up","10:10 AM"));
       callSMSList.add(new SMS("Rose","Bring me some chocolates","1035:10 AM"));
       // Set items to adapter
       callSMSAdapter.setCallSMSFeed(callSMSList);
       callSMSAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

I think the error is in not knowing how to obtain the value of each data within each object. Since each object is composed of 3 values which I must be able to search based on the search indicated by filters.

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't implement the filter, How could you get result?

Comment: use an adapter that already implements `Filterable` interface - in 99% writing own `Filter` is reinventing the wheel